# Symfony checkbox field default checked

Tags: symfony, checkbox, formbuilder

When I create a new entity, I want a certain checkbox to be checked by default. As the documentation says I used the data attribute, but now when I edit the same entity the checkbox is checked wether the value is 0 or 1.

How can I make it so that when I do a new entity, the checkbox is checked. but when I uncheck it, store the entity, and edit it, it uses the stored value ?

```
 $builder
            ->add(
                'naamOrganisatie',
                'text',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Naam organisatie',
                    'required' => false)
            )
            ->add('isOrganisatie', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, 'data' => true))
            ->add('naam', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('voornaam', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('vestigingsnummer');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init isOrganisatie data in entity constructor using:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->isOrganisatie = true;
}
```

You are overriding the value using data attribute in form.

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isOrganisatie = true;

Did the trick

Comment: is it normal your are using the boolean comparator == in the constructor ?

Comment: That's was a typo, I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

In  Entity/Object.php file

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->setIsOrganisatie(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize in Entity attribut for default value

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_organisatie", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isOrganisatie = true;
```